# how to extract month and year seperate from a given date in php?

Tags: php, date

I have a date `$da = '18-Nov-2015'`

I want month and year separate.I tried this.but it didn't work.

```
$month  =  date('F',strtotime($da));
$YEAR   =  date('Y',strtotime($da));
```

Comment: go with hardik answer.

Comment: This code works, what is the issue? http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/1z4j-i632

Answer (score 6):

Give it try with below code:

```
$da    =  '18-Nov-2015';
$date  =  DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M-Y',$da);
echo $date->format("Y");
echo $date->format("F");
```

> **Note:**`DateTime` We can create the object using arbitrary parameters like `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M-Y', $weird_user_input);` which can be formatted to unix timestamp or
>   whatever other date format We wish.

Comment: This is not very efficient if all components of the date are needed.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [date_parse()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php) function. It returns an array that contains the components of the date: day, month, year, hour, minute, and others.

Usage sample:

```
$da = '18-Nov-2015';
$dateComps = date_parse($da);
$year = $dateComps['year'];
$month = $dateComps['month'];
$day = $dateComps['day'];
//and so on, ...
```

Comment: works great, after test `$dateComps `  = `array(12) { ["year"]=> int(2015) ["month"]=> int(11) ["day"]=> int(18) ["hour"]=> bool(false) ["minute"]=> bool(false) ["second"]=> bool(false) ["fraction"]=> bool(false) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) ["warnings"]=> array(0) { } ["error_count"]=> int(0) ["errors"]=> array(0) { } ["is_localtime"]=> bool(false) }`

Comment: but this will return the integer values.

Answer (score -1):

Almost you have done.This is how you can do it.

```
$year = date('Y', strtotime($da));
$month = date('m', strtotime($da));
```

`F` - A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March    January through December

`m` - Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros 01 through 12

`M` - A short textual representation of a month, three letters  Jan through Dec

`n` -   Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros    1 through 12

Or else simply you can use `explode` method

```
$dateArray = explode('-', $da);
$dateArray[0] //date
$dateArray[1] //Month
$dateArray[2] //Year
```

Date reference : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score -1):

use

```
$da=new DateTime($da);
$da->format('m-d');
```

Comment: Could you add some details of why this should work? Code-only answers are not very useful and are subject to deletion.

Answer (score -1):

hello try this hope you will get your answer what you want.
let me know if you got iy correct.

```
<?php

$dateValue = Date('Y-m-d');
$time=strtotime($dateValue);
$year=date("Y",$time);
$month=date("F",$time);
$date=date("d",$time);

?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: but he doesn't want any explanation that's why i have just given the solution what he wanted. but ya for sure you are right , there must be explanation in the solution for the future point of view.                                                                         i 'll take care of it .                                                                                             jay blanchard.

Answer (score -2):

i tried this in http://phpfiddle.org/

```
$da='18-Nov-2015';
$dateValue = strtotime($da);
$year = date('Y',$dateValue);
$monthName = date('F',$dateValue);
$day = date('d',$dateValue);
echo $monthName;
echo $year;
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.